# What is the difference between filter () and {} in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, filter, predicate

I am studying Kotlin and facing some difficulties with understanding the difference between filter with parenthesis and curly braces. If I check filter implementation, Intellij redirects me to the same source.

Code example:

```
listOf("john", "dave").filter { name -> name.startsWith("j") }

// versus

// simple predicate function
fun getSimplePredicate(): (String) -> Boolean = 
  name: String -> name.firstName.startsWith(prefix)

// actual filter call
listOf("john", "dave).filter(getSimplePredicate())
```

What If I want to call somehow `filter { getSimplePredicate() }`?

Is there is a way? And what is the difference? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`filter()` expects a predicate function as argument, i.e. a function which takes a string and returns a boolean.

In Kotlin, if the last argument of a function (filter here) is a function (the predicate), then you can pass a lambda and the lambda can be out of the parentheses. So

```
.filter { ... }
```

is the same as

```
.filter({ ... })
```

So, in your code, `{ name -> name.startsWith("j") }` is a lambda which is the argument passed to `filter()`.

The function `getSimplePredicate()` *returns* a predicate function.

So `.filter(getSimplePredicate())` is equivalent to `.filter({ name.firstName.startsWith(prefix) })`, which is equivalent to `.filter { name.firstName.startsWith(prefix) }`.

`.filter { getSimplePredicate() }` would be valid if `{ getSimplePredicate() }` was a function that returns a Boolean, i.e. if `getSimplePredicate()` returned a Boolean. But it doesn't, so it's not valid.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation, now it makes total sense to me

Answer (score 2):

As JB Nizet mentions, this isn't specific to filtering, but is standard Kotlin syntax.  If you're calling a function with a lambda as the last parameter, e.g.:

```
list.map({ size -> size * 2 })
```

Then **you can move the lambda outside the parentheses**:

```
list.map(){ size -> size * 2 }
```

(That's mainly to allow functions that look like new language syntax.  But it's useful generally.)  And **if there's nothing left in them, you can omit the parentheses entirely**:

```
list.map{ size -> size * 2 }
```

Also, if a lambda has exactly one parameter (and the compiler can infer its type), then you can refer to it as `it` instead of naming it explicitly:

```
list.map{ it * 2 }
```

**All four forms mean exactly the same thing**: they're calling the `map()` function with a lambda.  (You'll see those sorts of syntactic shortcuts a lot; they can help to make code easier to read.)

OK, on to your code:

Your first line works, but your predicate function needs a few tweaks before it'll compile.  The signature is fine, but the definition won't work without braces.  (In Scala and Java, the arrow is the distinguishing part; but we've just seen how you can omit that in Kotlin, so **every lambda must have braces**.)

Also, you haven't defined `firstName` or `prefix`.  I'm going to assume that we can ignore the former, and provide the latter as a parameter.  With a bit of simplification, that gives:

```
fun getSimplePredicate(prefix: String): (String) -> Boolean
    = { it.startsWith(prefix) }
```

And **with those tweaks, you can indeed use it to provide a predicate for filtering**, e.g.:

```
listOf("john", "dave").filter(getSimplePredicate("j"))
```

(Note that this time, there are no curly braces, as we're not creating a lambda in this line — the function has already done that.)

Of course, in this case, it's actually simpler to provide a lambda directly, as per your first example!  But this illustrates the principle.

There's one other option that's worth covering, too, which is a function reference.  If you already had a function that would do the job, you don't need to put it in a lambda, but can refer to it directly, using the `::` notation.  For example:

```
fun hasValidPrefix(s: String) = s.startsWith("j")

listOf("john", "dave").filter(::hasValidPrefix)
```

That only works if the parameter type(s) are compatible, but it's slightly simpler (and can generate slightly more efficient bytecode).

All of these are explained [in the Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html).